# question about altering date column in table with postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

i created table with 4column with

```
create table conversation(
    user_name varchar(200),
    employer_name varchar(200),
    message text,
    date_sent timestamp
)
```

now i want alter date_sent column without remove it i want to set default value of current_timestamp for this column what i must do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE conversation ALTER COLUMN  
date_sent SET DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

> ```
> create table conversation(
> user_name varchar(200), 
> employer_name varchar(200), 
> message text, 
> date_sent timestamp );
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE conversation ALTER COLUMN  
> date_sent SET DEFAULT current_timestamp;
> ```

> ```
> insert into conversation 
> (user_name) values
> ('me');
> ```

> ```
> select * from conversation;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_name | employer_name | message | date_sent                 
> :-------- | :------------ | :------ | :-------------------------
> me        | null          | null    | 2022-04-01 09:38:13.674547
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3853f7e78d3ebf19dc616d4ba8a450b8)*